# JS fine in Fiddle but doesn't animate until browser resize on Squarespace site

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope, jsfiddle, squarespace

I'm using jQuery Isotope to animate images on my site. It works fine in jsFiddle but the animation refuses to initialise until I resize the browser on the site itself.

I have looked at other related questions and tried wrapping the code in a ready function and looking for hidden characters but nothing seems to work. The site is:

http://rgbdrinks.squarespace.com

and the fiddle is:

http://jsfiddle.net/tutmoses/kxLck/3/

Any help gratefully received.

Andrew

---

```
<div id="container">

<div class="item"><div id="squarespace-slideshow-wrapper-1371031439" rel="51b847e2e4b0552c3a104be5" class="ss-slideshow-v2"></div><p>This is a test</p></div>

<div class="item"><img style="width: 150px;" src="/picture/drink%20pour%203.jpg?pictureId=18133348&amp;asGalleryImage=true&amp;__SQUARESPACE_CACHEVERSION=1370962041640" alt="" /></div>

<div class="item"><img style="width: 150px;" src="/picture/martini%20glass%20splash.jpg?pictureId=18133349&amp;asGalleryImage=true&amp;__SQUARESPACE_CACHEVERSION=1370962058097" alt="" /></div>

<div class="item"><img style="width: 150px;" src="/picture/tablecloth.jpg?pictureId=18133350&amp;asGalleryImage=true&amp;__SQUARESPACE_CACHEVERSION=1370962092184" alt="" /></div>

<div class="item"><div id="squarespace-slideshow-wrapper-1370943850" rel="51b6f18ae4b0877f36bb6468" class="ss-slideshow-v2"></div></div>

<div class="item"><div id="squarespace-slideshow-wrapper-1371031528" rel="51b84800e4b0552c3a104be6" class="ss-slideshow-v2"></div></div>

<div class="item"><div id="squarespace-slideshow-wrapper-1371031555" rel="51b8481be4b0552c3a104be7" class="ss-slideshow-v2"></div></div>

<div class="item"><div id="squarespace-slideshow-wrapper-1371031585" rel="51b8483ee4b0552c3a104be8" class="ss-slideshow-v2"></div></div>


</div>

<script src="http://rgbdrinks.squarespace.com/storage/isotope/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://rgbdrinks.squarespace.com/storage/isotope/js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://rgbdrinks.squarespace.com/storage/isotope/js/fake-element.js"></script>



<script>

var $container = $('#container')

    // initialize Isotope

$container.isotope({

    // options...
    sortBy : 'random',
    resizable : true,
    itemSelector : '.item',
    animationEngine : 'best-available',
    // set columnWidth to a percentage of container width
    masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 6 }

});

    // update columnWidth on window resize
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).smartresize(function(){

    $container.isotope({
    // update columnWidth to a percentage of container width
    masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 6 }
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: Instead of `$(document).ready(function() {...})` have you tried `$(window).on('load',function(){...})` ?

Comment: Just tried it and haven't noticed any difference. I'm not sure that the ready function is in the right place though anyway. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: Ah-ha! I moved the load function to the beginning of the script and it worked. Thanks so much!